# javascript file reader not working in chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

I am using following code to upload and preview image using js, when i select the image from computer , it previews the image properly , but when i try to upload the image again and click 'cancel', it removes the previously selected image , but in firefox it does not. , what might be issue with chrome?

```
function readURL(input) {
    jQuery("#image_view1").hide();
    if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function (e) {
            jQuery("#image_view").html("<img id='image_view' src='"+ e.target.result+"' alt='your image' style='width: 240px; height: 130px; '/></br>");
        };

        reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
    }
}
```

Html :

```
<form action="" method="post" id="frmGallery" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="mediaSliderForm">
    <div class="control-group clearfix"><h2>Add Image</h2></div>
    <div class="control-group clearfix"><label>Title : </label><input type="text" name="title" class="required"></div>
    <div class="control-group clearfix"><label>Category : </label>
        <select class="required testimonialCategory" name="category">
            <option value="">Select Category</option>
            <?php  foreach($categories as $category){
                    echo $cat_id == $category->term_id ? '<option value="'.$category->term_id.'" selected="true">'.$category->name.'</option>' : '<option value="'.$category->term_id.'">'.$category->name.'</option>';
        }?>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="control-group clearfix"><label>Image: </label> <input type="file" name="image" id="image" class="required" onchange="readURL(this);"></div>
    <div class="control-group clearfix"><label>&nbsp;</label><div id="image_view" class="advImg"></div></div>
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-small btn-inverse" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Can you also post the relevant html?

Comment: added the html form, but i think there is no any issue related with form, as this works perfectly in firefox

Comment: I can see an issue immediately, but each browser handles problems differently.  For example, in your JS you add an image with the ID "image_view" to an element with the same ID.  IDs should be unique.  Also, you don't close the input tag.  This will generally get ignored but can cause problems, especially if you're seeing different behaviour in different browsers.

Comment: Anyway, we need the html to both rule out any issues and to also be able to try and reproduce your problem.

Comment: I can only suggest getting rid of `jQuery("#image_view1").hide();` as I can't reproduce your problem and that's the only unknown that I have.  See here... http://jsfiddle.net/DxysZ/

Comment: Tried to remove  jQuery("#image_view1").hide(); but still didn't work

Comment: Then I can't help you.  If you check the jsfiddle I linked what you describe does not happen, so it's something that we've got no info about.

Comment: Ohh, I am sorry, i think you did not get my issue, if you see when i try to select the image second time, and click on cancel, the previously selected image is there, but you are getting the text like 'No file choosen' that is path is unlinked from previously selected image, but this is not happened in Firfox

Comment: The choose file should not be reset to 'No file choosen'